# Trying to delete multiple files from a single directory whose names match\contain a particular string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to delete image files. The files are named `somefile.jpg` and `somefile_t.jpg`, the file with the `_t` on the end is the thumbnail. With this delete operation I wish to delete both the thumbnail and original image.

The code works up until the `foreach` loop, where the `GetFiles` method returns nothing.
The string.Substring operation successfully returns just the file name with no extension and no `_t` e.g: `somefile`.

There are no invalid characters in the file names I wish to delete.
Code looks good to me, only thing I can think of is that I am somehow not using the searchpattern
function properly.

```
filesource = "~/somedir/somefile_t.jpg"
```

---

```
var dir = Server.MapPath(filesource);


            FileInfo FileToDelete = new FileInfo(dir);


            if (FileToDelete.Exists) 
            { 
                var FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileToDelete.Name);

                foreach(FileInfo file in FileToDelete.Directory.GetFiles(FileName.Substring(0, FileName.Length - 2), SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList())
               {
                   file.Delete();
               }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DirectoryInfo.GetFiles Method (String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx)

You need to ensure that the first parameter, *searchPattern*, is proper. In you're case you are supplying `FileName.Substring(0, FileName.Length - 2)`, which would be **"somefile"**. The reason the method returns nothing is because you are looking for files literally named somefile. What you meant to do was to use a wildcard in addition to the base filename: `String.Concat(FileName.Substring(0, FileName.Length - 2), "*")`, which would be **"somefile*"** ... at least I think you're looking for that *searchPattern* as opposed to any other one.

Comment: Thanks that worked, wonder why it doesn't work with something like FileName.Substring(0, FileName.Length - 2) + "*", but does when using the String.Concat ? Probably does not evaluate the joined string, just the part before the +

Comment: It would work with `FileName.Substring(0, FileName.Length - 2) + "*"` because that's what `String.Concat(...)` is doing, but your original code does not have the wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
        var file_path = @"K:\Work\IoCToy\IoCToy\image.jpg";
        var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(file_path);
        var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file_path);
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, string.Format("{0}*", fileNameWithoutExtension), SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Of course, you have to delete the files by the returned file names. I am assuming here that your folder contains only the image and the thumbnail file which start with the "image" substring.